# Getting Undefined When Passing in FormData to Redux Register Function in Reactjs with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, form-data

I am creating a registration functionality with redux. I have setup the store and reducer and the `function register()`.

However, when I call the endpoint for the registration api it just doesnt register the user and from the redux actions file i get undefined for all of my data.

whenever i go to my redux dev tools i see that it says "Name is Required", "Username is Required", which are backend validation i have set up from my nodejs api, meaning that no values are reaching the api and everything i enter is undefined. Why is that?

I am new to redux so i don't know how to debug the issue or understand what is going wrong.

Here is my code:

actions/auth.js file:

```
export const register = ({ name, uniID, username, email, phoneNumber, uniIDImage, password }) => async dispatch => {
 
    console.log(name, email, phoneNumber, uniIDImage, password);//logs undefined
    const body = JSON.stringify({ name, uniID, username, email, phoneNumber, uniIDImage, password });
    const emailBody = JSON.stringify({ name, email });

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/register', body);

        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type:REGISTER_FAIL,
        });
    }

}
```

reducers/auth.js:

```
import {
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL,
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {

    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                loading: false
            }
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                loading: false
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Register.js:

```
import React, {useEffect, useReducer, useState} from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import axios from "axios"

import { register } from '../../actions/auth';

const Register = ({ register }) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: '',
    uniID: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const [uniIDImage, setUniIDImage] = useState([]);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  const handleImage = (e) => {
    e.persist()
    setUniIDImage({ pic: e.target.files[0] });
  }

  const onRegister = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", data.name);
    formData.append("uniID", data.uniID);
    formData.append("username", data.username);
    formData.append("email", data.email);
    formData.append("phoneNumber", data.phoneNumber);
    formData.append("uniIDImage", uniIDImage.pic);
    formData.append("password", data.password);


    register({formData});
  }

Register.propTypes = {
  register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, {register})(Register);
```

Comment: What's the point of using FormData and then converting it to a JSON object? JSON is a text format, you can't append a file/blob to it unless your server expects the file to be encoded as a base64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing "formData" type

```
 // this is correct
 register(formData);
```

but you are destructuring like a regular object

```
export const register = ({ name, uniID, username, email, phoneNumber, uniIDImage, password }) => async dispatch => {
```

If you check this [mdn formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/values)

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key1', 'value1');
formData.append('key2', 'value2');

// Display the values
for (const value of formData.values()) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

when you received the `formData` inside `register` convert it to an object

```
export const register =(formData) => async(dispatch)=> {
  let jsonObject = {};
  for (let key of FormData.keys()) {
    jsonObject[key] = formData.get(key);
  }

  // in axios post jsonObject

  const res = await axios.post('/register', jsonObject);
};
```

Comment: yes i just found out that i missed that part so i added it like this register({formData}) but it still doesn't work and sends the data as undefined, whilst when i do the display of the values, everything is there. why is that?

Comment: this is a perfect solution, but now i am getting an error in my backend because i am  trying to upload an image using multer. the error reads `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')`  this is the line of code  `const uniIDImage = url + "/images/" + req.file.filename;`

Comment: @motionless570 because you did not add it to formData. if you are working with multer i think you have to send the data in formData with the `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Thank you, i added the content type and it worked! thank you so much for the help